# Stretch div to max size

Tags: html, css

My css:

```
#main {
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 55px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
}

#content {
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

What i want:
[image]

What i get:
[image]

Red = absolute header 
White = #main with "blue" scrollbars 
Green = #content border with the text in it.

I guess it is quite easy to solve but i still couldnt manage after trying for ages :P

Updated/simplified jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YAgW2/9/

Comment: could you post this to http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @Niko , you want that your #content one with green color should extend as you show in Image No 1 , where do yuo set the width of your #content , post html as well

Comment: Added jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/YAgW2/2/ , see yourself

Comment: Oh forgot adding "white-space: nowrap;" to #content

Comment: Provide `width` to your `#content`.

Comment: i can't provide a fixed value since the content is extended automatically. And 100% and "auto" do not work properly since #main is absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding float: left; to #content solves the display issue!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not move `#content` outside of `#main` and position it where you want, i.e. on top of `#main`?

Comment: Well i want to scroll #content in the #main div, so i guess i can't.

Comment: Maybe I'm not entirely sure what you mean...  Would overflow:scroll; applied to #content do what you want?

Comment: As you can see it looks aweful, obviously i want it to look properly :/

Comment: But is the structure now correct?  If so, you can change shape/colour of the scrollbars using CSS/JS.

Comment: What do you mean with structure? Just take a look at the link and scroll to the right. Looks like #content simply breaks at the end of the page instead of being extended. And i do not care about the look of the scrollbars, i just want them to be there and #content being extended properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should be:

```
#main {
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 55px;
  max-width: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
}

#content {
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
  margin: 5px;
  width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Then i get a scrollbar from body and my vertical scrollbar is not visible. #main seems to be correct since that is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following **CSS**:

```
#main {
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 55px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
}

#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

And the following **HTML**:

```
<div>
<div id="main">

</div>
<div id="content" style="position:absolute">
    Try to extend this text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want the #content to be in #main else #main is totally useless anyway isn't it?